# Вывести из JSON массива данные в html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Вот JS

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      index: "1"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var json = response;
        console.log(json);
    }
 });
```

Вот PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['index'])) {
    $index = strip_tags($_POST['index']);
    if($index == "1") {
        $res = array(
            'name' => 'Den',
            'age' => '30'
        );
        echo json_encode($res);
        die();      
    }
}
```

Выводит в консоли

{"name":"Den","age":"30"}

Вот такой JS

```
console.log(json.name +"  "+ json.age);
```

Не выводит "Den  30". Не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно спарсить json через `JSON.parse()` ([подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)), а потом уже выводить отдельные его элементы:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      index: "1"
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var json = JSON.parse(response);        // парсинг полученного json
        console.log(json.name +"  "+ json.age); // вывод результата
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

По дефолту `$.ajax` сам догадывается какой тип данных приходит от сервера. Но если нужно указать прям точно железобетонно что ожидаешь `json`, то достаточно добавить строку

```
dataType: 'json',
```

к остальным параметрам ajax, т.е.

```
url: "mail.php",
method: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
```

А сейчас возможно это воспринимается как строка.